# How to find out if there is any real pattern in the data set?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, independence

Let's assume that we have a regression problem (in the machine learning sense). Our data set consists of pairs of features vectors and numeric targets.

It might be the case that there is absolutely no relation between features and targets. How can we detect those situations? I would like to have a test such that we do not miss any weak relation. In other words, if the test says that there is no relation, we can be quite sure that there is really nothing in the data and it does not make any sense to build a predictive model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already checked for basic things like correlation.

People usually just fit a very flexible non-parametric model (such as random forest) and see if it can do better than chance on some hold-out test set. If it can, it suggests the two variables are not totally independent.

Another approach is the calculate the empirical mutual information. For example, in R, this can be done via [infotheo::mutinformation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/infotheo/versions/1.2.0/topics/mutinformation) or [entropy::mi.empirical](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/entropy.pdf).

No (currently available) approach will be able to detect *all* possible relationships though. Consider stenography - we could hide mutual information in the least significant bits of the numbers in such a way that no one could ever detect it.

Comment: The first sentence in your last paragraph is key.  One has to conduct a lot of exploratory analysis (univariate and multivariate) in machine learning.  There may be some outliers in data that lead to weak relationships and that have to be handled first.

Comment: @olooney, isn't the case that the more flexible (expressive) model will tend to lear random patterns (because of over-fit) and therefore it will tend to give worse (less statistically significant) result out-of-sample? Shouldn't we start from a simple model?

Comment: @Roman, it could. Any one particular model could fail to identify a real relationship. The design of random forest, with its random subspaces and bootstrap aggregation, make it unlikely to simply memorize the training set, but it's not impossible. As a practical matter, if I personally saw RF completely fail to do better than chance on a at-least medium sized data set with default hyper-parameters, then I would be very suspicious of any other model that claimed to identify a relationship. (continued in next comment for length...)

Comment: If you're worried about it, you can simply throw more models at the wall, from simple and complex, trying different algorithms and hyper-parameters, to see if anything sticks. This is called [model selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection) and you can find lots of resources by googling that phrase. A key point is that each model is a separate hypothesis, so as we test more and more models there is a greater and greater chance of a false positive unless we apply a [multiple hypothesis correction](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jtaylo/courses/stats203/notes/selection.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Look up Restricted Boltzmann Machines. Honestly any unsupervised learning algorithm should work, as they will show you correlations in the data (clustering algorithms, or heck even PCA). After running the algorithms you can trace the correlations to specific points in the data, and see if the correlations can be used for your regression purposes.

Meaning... if all the data vectors which you want to be class A cluster together, and class B clusters together then there is a correlation.

Restricted Boltzmann Machines take an extra step by creating a (or multiple) layer of hidden nodes, if the hidden nodes can reconstruct the original data then they have found strong features and correlations in the data.

I know it's a broad answer, but there are a ton of unsupervised learning algorithms out there! Which one works best, of course depends on your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for offering an answer as a new contributor on CrossValidated. One way to make answers more helpful to the original poster (OP) and to the community at large would be to use [Markdown formatting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to embed hyperlinks to your favorite references on the several topics you mention, and to give some indication why these might be worth clicking on.